# SSL Certificate Name Mismatch Error on digital ocean

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, nginx, server, ssl-certificate

There is already ssl certificate on the server, the issue is it works fine if someone writes website as borroup.com but when write www.borroup.com it says connection not secure. Im not sure how to access the cert from the server to config the issue.

borroup.com
[image]
[image]

www.borroup.com
[image]
[image]

here is the sudo ls /etc
[image]

I tried this

```
sudo certbot --nginx -d  borroup.com -d www.borroup.com
```

and this

```
sudo ./letsencrypt-auto --apache -d borroup.com  -d www.borroup.com
```

i kept getting command not found

```
command not found
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a site for Let's Encrypt tutorials, but you need to generate a SAN certificate to cover both domains.